# Производительность асинхронных операций asio под Windows

Tags: c++, boost, asio

Наткнулся на странную проблему с asio - c UDP-сокетами под Windows. Написал пару простых программ для оценки производительности обмена через UDP: сервер, повторяющий пришедшее сообщение, и клиент, генерящий очереди (по 10000 сообщений, строки, содержащие номер в виде шестизначного числа), пересылающий их через UDP и выкидывающий сообщения из очереди, когда приходит ответ. Пересылка сделана с помощью асинхронных функций `socket.async_receive_from` и `socket.async_send_to`. Клиент генерирует очередь, посылает и проверяет подтверждающие ответы и измеряет время, которое на это потребовалось.

Первые 30000 сообщений проходят достаточно быстро, но потом (я поэкспериментировал с длиной очереди и обнаружил, что падение скорости проходит после 32000 сообщений) скорость падает на порядки, при этом клиент загружает одно ядро на 100%. Программы писались под Windows (W10, MinGW). Я попытался выяснить, где же происходит падение производительности, и, чтобы использовать Valgrind, пересобрал код под Ubuntu (15.10), запущенную в виртуальной машине Virtualbox. Обнаружил, что под Ubuntu падения скорости нет, причём, несмотря на виртуализацию, скорость такая же, как и вне виртуальной машины под Windows.

Попытался исключить подозреваемых. Попробовал разные версии GCC (от 4.6.2 до 4.9.2) в MinGW, собрал под Visual Studio 2013, попробовал как `boost::asio`, так и standalone-версию asio. Результат один - после 32000 сообщений скорость резко падает. Померил производительность через gprof - максимум процессорного времени ест `asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::do_one`. На этом я попал в тупик.

Я ещё могу предположить, чем вызвана ситуация - например, какой-то встроенный кэш в asio переполняется. Но я не понимаю, куда копать дальше. Почему UDP-пакеты, летающие через localhost внутри виртуальной машины Ubuntu, продолжают летать, а такие же пакеты в "родной" Windows начинают тормозить? Они же на одном железе и даже в одной и той же Windows летают. Почему в такой широко используемой библиотеке, как `asio`, встретилась такая проблема? И в ней ли она встретилась - вдруг всё-таки в моём коде? А если в нём, то почему под Linux мой код работает нормально? В общем, жду каких-то советов или хотя бы предположений, а то пока что ничего кроме как "исключать Windows из списка поддерживаемых платформ" или "искать другой фреймворк" в голову не приходит, а оба варианта не прикольные.

**Update**: решение найдено, подробно описано в комментарии. Вкратце: я генерировал запрос `async_receive_from` и после каждой отправки, и после каждого приёма, получалась утечка ресурса.

Comment: Из похожего на английском SO нашел только это http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431755/boost-asio-will-send-fast-and-then-very-slow, хотя вроде встречал подобную проблему там недавно. Еще есть мысль что межсетевой экран может как-то влиять.

Comment: Ох, спасибо! Я эту запись не нашёл, попробую поковырять. А сетевой экран отключать я пробовал, никаких изменений не было.

Comment: Увы, не помогло. Пробовал играть размерами буфера, от 16К до 1024К, но никаких изменений не получается. Картина примерно такая:   Elapsed time: 0.602, 16611.3 mps
Elapsed time: 0.592, 16891.9 mps
Elapsed time: 0.591, 16920.5 mps
Elapsed time: 7.873, 1270.16 mps
Elapsed time: 17.374, 575.573 mps
Elapsed time: 27.319, 366.046 mps
Elapsed time: 39.762, 251.496 mps

Comment: На Windows существует глобальный лок на уровне ядра (по крайней мере на версиях страше 10ой, ее я не видел), который при серверной (т.е. большой) нагрузке на сеть даёт резкое падение производительности. Детали не помню, но сталкивался.
На Linux, возможно, у Вас это не воспроизводится, потому что используется эмулятор сетевого интерфейса внутри wmware (т.е. не факт, что вы задействуете сетевой интерфейс компа, доступ до которого через windows), а этот эмулятор может не иметь такой проблемы. Кроме того, этот эмулятор может давать намного более красивый результат, чем был бы на реальном железе.

Comment: Arkady, спасибо, попробую на Windows Server 2012 R2 - наш админ обещал дать доступ.

Comment: Попробовал на виртуальной машине с W7 и на "железной" WS 2012 R2. Проблема воспроизводится везде. Итог: исключаем Windows из списка поддерживаемых платформ.

Comment: вот что нашёл сегодня http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875210/long-delays-in-sending-udp-packets, если ещё актуально

Comment: Yuriy Orlov, спасибо, но проблема оказалась в другом - я описал решение в комментарии ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, виноват был я, недостаточно разобрался с asio.

Когда я отправляю пакет (в handler'е отправки), я там же вызываю функцию, запускающую ожидание пакета. И в handler'е получения тоже. В результате запускается очень много `async_receive_from`'ов, и система смертельно тормозит.

Под Linux, видимо, есть "защита от дурака". Когда я убрал лишний вызов `async_receive_from`, всё заработало прекрасно - 80К-150К сообщений на одном узле, 20К через Wi-Fi между узлами, 45K через Gigabit Ethernet.